# Efficient way of applying a savitzky golay filtering on data.table rows for certain column?

Tags: r, data.table

I wrote a function to apply a savitzky golay filter to each row in a data.table. The first column having measurement values is given as an argument and all later columns contain measurements values to be filtered too. The processed rows are updated in-place.

My function works, but is slow.

How could the function be changed in order to work more efficient and more data.table like?

MWE:

```
library(data.table)
library(pracma)
library(datasets)

data(iris)
setDT(iris)

#Reorder columns because function expects columns to apply a filter on 
#starting from a defined column to the last column
setcolorder(iris, "Species")


savitzky_golay <- function(dt, id_of_first_sample_col=2, win_size=5) {
  
  c_names_samples <- colnames(dt)[id_of_first_sample_col:ncol(dt)]
  
  for (i in seq(from=1, to=nrow(dt))) {
    mat <- as.numeric(dt[i,id_of_first_sample_col:ncol(dt)]) # Get sample data as matrix (one row)
    mat <- savgol(mat,fl=win_size,forder=2,dorder=0) # Savitzky-Golay-Filter
    
    dt[i, (c_names_samples) := as.list(mat)] # Update columns of current row by reference
  }
  # Returns nothing as update is done via reference.
}

savitzky_golay(iris)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
savitzky_golay_new <- function(dt, id_of_first_sample_col=2, win_size=5) {
  c_names_samples <- colnames(dt)[id_of_first_sample_col:ncol(dt)]
  dt[,(c_names_samples):=asplit(apply(.SD,1,function(x) savgol(x,fl=win_size,forder=2,dorder=0)),1)
     ,.SDcols=c_names_samples]
  }
```

performance comparison:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(savitzky_golay_new(dt2),savitzky_golay(dt1))
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 savitzky_golay_new(dt2) 12.7808 13.69695 15.63821 14.31785 15.17705  31.2701   100
     savitzky_golay(dt1) 71.4231 81.96115 87.97737 86.41265 90.42620 239.7945   100
```